# getting "not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'list'" when adding object to priority queue

Tags: python, class, sorting, huffman-code

Im trying to add a pair of elements to a priority queue.
When I try to add an element im getting this error:

```
"TypeError: < not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'list'"
```

Should I use another way to add element to priorityQueue instead of .put() ?

Im trying to figure a Huffman node

```py
import queue
S = "testString"
map = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)]
aux = auxTemp = list()
freqs = list()

def repsInS(S,map):
    reps = 0
    for i, value in enumerate(map):
        for j, value in enumerate(S):
            if(map[i]==S[j]):
                reps+=1
        aux.append(map[i])
        aux.append(reps)
        auxTemp = aux.copy()
        freqs.append(auxTemp)
        aux.clear()
        reps = 0
        freqs.sort(key= lambda x:x[1])
    return freqs

frecuencias = repsInS(S,map)

class NodoHuffman(object):
    def __init__(self, left=None, right=None, root=None):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.root = root

    def hijoTemp(self):
        return((self.left, self.right))


def HuffmanTree(frecuencias):
    objs = queue.PriorityQueue()
    for i in frecuencias:
        objs.put(i)

    while (objs.qsize() > 1):
            left = objs.get()
            right = objs.get()
            newNode = NodoHuffman(left,right)
            objs.put((left[1]+right[1],newNode))
    return objs.get()

huff = HuffmanTree(frecuencias)
```

Comment: From what I can tell, you could just swap this line `objs.put((left[1]+right[1],newNode))` with `objs.put([left[1]+right[1],newNode])` if the only difference is the type. If you don't mind, could you show us what the `HuffmanNode` class is?

Comment: Can you show how do you call the classes you described as well

Comment: Why are you doing `for i in frecuencias` but then not doing anything with `i`? It looks like you might have omitted code, because `objs` is empty so `while objs.qsize() > 1` will never be `True` (so the `objs.put(...)` should never be reached).

Comment: @GeeTransit code Updated

Comment: @BaileyParker code updated

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh code updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the culprit behind the error :).

The way the `queue.PriorityQueue` class works is by storing a list of items. Whenever you `.put` something in, it will compare it using `<` and `>` to find the spot to insert it into. '.get' will simply pop it out from the already sorted list.

Because of the fact that the `tuple` and `list` cannot be compared, the `.put` fails. This may also be because you can change the list after, causing the priority queue to break.

A simple fix is to change the line in `repsInS` with `freqs.append([t, reps])` into `freqs.append((t, reps))`.

EDIT: Looks like there's more... The priority queue orders them using the object's rich comparison magic methods. Instead, I've made them use a normal list and have the Node save its own weight. This saves complexity in the class and makes the code more understandable.

Here is the fixed and polished code.

```py
import queue

test_str = 'testString'
test_list = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)]


class HuffmanNode:
    def __init__(self, weight, left=None, right=None, info=None):
        self.weight = weight
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.info = info

    def hijoTemp(self):
        return self.left, self.right


def get_repeats(S, T):
    freqs = []

    for t in T:
        reps = 0
        for s in S:
            if s == t:
                reps += 1
        freqs.append((reps, t))

    freqs.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
    return freqs # Return list of lists


def create_huffman_tree(freqs):
    objs = [HuffmanNode(w, info=l) for w, l in freqs]
    objs.sort(key=lambda node: node.weight, reverse=True)

    while len(objs) > 1:
        left, right = objs.pop(), objs.pop()
        weight = left.weight + right.weight
        objs.put(HuffmanNode(weight, left, right))

    return objs.pop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    frecuencias = get_repeats(test_str, test_list)
    huffman_tree = create_huffman_tree(frecuencias)
```